# Relationship between DC speed control module and dc motor

Tags: dc-motor, amperage

Good Morning! I have a minnkota trolling motor that pulls 50a @ 36vdc (per the spec sheet). This unit leads a hard life (routinely running through mud and weeds which would be increasing resistive load? And also long periods at 100% with LOTS of starts and stops. So basically it is being used in an off label manner that the minnkota engineers didn’t really design for). The issue I am attempting to solve for is the power control board mounted in the head of the unit. I would like to upgrade to a more robust power control module. From an engineering standpoint is it as simple as hooking up a remote mounted 100a rated, air cooled, power control module? Will this actually reduce the heat (which I believe is the main culprit) being generated in the board? Or do power control modules have some control over amp draw that I am not considering and I will promptly melt the brushes in the motor? Considering an Amazon unit for proof of concept but then would like to build my own eventually. As a disclaimer, electrical engineering fascinated me and I am not a blooming idiot but if I tried to tell you that I know what I’m doing, I might be a liar. Thanks!

Comment: Frame challenge : as it's a brush motor, you may find upgrading to a considerably more efficient brushless motor is a better deal.